# How to limit decimal places to 2 in this sql query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL Query:

```
select u.user_name, sum(r.goals) total_goals, sum(r.goals)/(2 * count(1)) avg_goals 
from (select community_id, player1_id id, player1_goals goals 
from results union all select community_id, player2_id, player2_goals from results) r 
inner join users u on r.id = u.id 
where r.community_id = 16 group by r.id, u.user_name 
ORDER BY avg_goals DESC
```

Which produces a result such as 
`"avg_goals" , "1.2500"`  ( I am only interested in this column for this instance)

How do I limit the decimal places in the result to just 2?  So the output would be `1.25` instead of `1.2500`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`ROUND(col, 2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

```
select u.user_name, sum(r.goals) total_goals, round(sum(r.goals)/(2 * count(1)),2) avg_goals 
from (select community_id, player1_id id, player1_goals goals 
from results union all select community_id, player2_id, player2_goals from results) r 
inner join users u on r.id = u.id 
where r.community_id = 16 group by r.id, u.user_name 
ORDER BY avg_goals DESC
```

As @scaisEdge said, You can alternatively use truncate(col,2) if you just want to truncate the rest of the digits.

Answer (score 0):

You  should use TRUNCATE eg:

```
   SELECT TRUNCATE(1.2500,2) from dual ;


   SELECT TRUNCATE(round(sum(r.goals)/(2 * count(1)),2), 2) .....
```